# i have a probel on getting data from data base while im trying to get the name and the phone number of the user

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

[image: screen shot about the code return always null]

```
 }
        var reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("utilisateur")
        reference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{

            override fun onDataChange(p0: DataSnapshot) {
                textViewEmailAdress.setText(user!!.getEmail())
         val utilisateur = p0.getValue(utilisateur_data:: class.java)

                    numtel.text = utilisateur!!.phone
                    prenom.text = utilisateur!!.name


            }
```

and this is the json firebase 
`"Utilisateurs" : {
    "-M8pC_JO_685-Htg4mJv" : {
      "confpass" : "Qwerty1@",
      "email" : "-M8pC_JO_685-Htg4mJv",
      "id" : "ahmed",
      "name" : "ahmed3@yopmail.com",
      "password" : "Qwerty1@",
      "phone" : "50596473"
    },
    "-M8uu0lnWnK6lqlEQ3EW" : {
      "confpass" : "momo998",
      "email" : "-M8uu0lnWnK6lqlEQ3EW",
      "id" : "salmen ",
      "name" : "salmen@gmail.com",
      "password" : "momo998",
      "phone" : "55667788"
    }`
"utilisateur" 
is the path of my database where I'm stoking information 
the problem is that I cant get the name and the phone number it return always null

Comment: the error is about that i cant get the name and the phone number from the fire base its return always null

Comment: Please edit your question (there's a link right under it) to show the JSON in your database at `/utilisateur` (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in the overflow menu (⠇) on your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: Please add some details or Pics of your firease database

Comment: Please add what Frank van Puffelen asked for and please also respond with @.

Comment: i added the JSON

Comment: You need the data of a single user or from all users?

Comment: from all users @Al